# Titanium: How to hide the actionBar in a non-Alloy project?

Tags: android, mobile, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have no problem hiding the action bar in an Alloy project.
However, how do I do this in a non-Alloy project?

I tried this:

```
win.activity.actionBar.hide();
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">            
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Add this to TiApp.xml

Answer (score 6):

Via `win.activity.actionBar.hide();` you can only hide the Action Bar when your window is finally opened. The main disadvantage is that sometimes you can see the Action Bar for a few milliseconds, because the window is initially created with Action Bar.

Since Titanium SDK 4.2.0 there are 4 predefined themes
to hide the Action Bar:

`Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar`

`Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

`Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar`

`Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

see http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes-section-34636181_AndroidThemes-TitaniumThemes

Besides globally setting the theme in TiApp.xml (see Wang Dan's answer) one can hide the Action Bar via `theme` property of `Ti.UI.Window`.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    // ...
    theme: "Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar"
});
```

Note that this is a creation-only property, so `win.theme = "Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar";` does not work.