# Hide the action bar on Android on Titanium/ Alloy/ Appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

How do I hide the action bar on Android on Alloy/ Titanium. I have tried the following:

```
$.index.activity.actionBar.hide()
```

but it just throws the error:

```
 Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined
```

The full error message is as follows:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1605,1605] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,1605] - In /alloy/controllers/index.js:359,27
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,1606] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,1606] - Source:     win.activity.actionBar.hide();
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at /alloy/controllers/index.js:359: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Titanium: How to hide actionBar in non-Alloy project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462817/titanium-how-to-hide-actionbar-in-non-alloy-project)

Comment: Solutions shows the proper way to hide the actionbar (using a theme or when to call the `hide()` method)

Comment: @miga I can't seem to find a solution as to when to call the hide function. They only provide an alternative method by providing a theme to the window.

Comment: see `Via win.activity.actionBar.hide(); you can only hide the Action Bar when your window is finally opened. The main disadvantage is that sometimes you can see the Action Bar for a few milliseconds, because the window is initially created with Action Bar` So you use this in your `open` event. It is easier to use the `NoTitleBar` theme in your tss though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are few things that you need to look at:

**Ques 1** - Do you want to hide Action Bar for all windows (means for whole app)?

**Ques 2** - Do you want to hide Action Bar after a window is opened and upon performing some action (means on some click or scroll)?

**Ques 3** - Do you want to hide Action Bar for few windows and show it for other windows?

---

**Answer 1: - Using in-built Titanium themes**

Method 1 - use this tag in tiapp.xml file:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Method 2 - set ***theme*** property in **app.tss**:

```
"Window[platform=android]":{
    theme : 'Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar'
}
```

---

**Answer 2:**

This is the case where you faced that issue. Hiding action bar by code in .js file is only possible when window is opened. You will have to use **window's onOpen event** to run this code:

```
$.index.activity.actionBar.hide();
```

So, it must be like this:

```
$.index.addEventListener('open', function () {
   $.index.activity.actionBar.hide();
});
```

Or you can run hide() method on some button click because you will be able to click on a button when obviously that window is opened, like this:

```
$.someButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
   $.index.activity.actionBar.hide();
});
```

---

**Answer 3:**

By using **Method 2** of **Answer 1**, you can apply theme in **.tss or .xml** file to hide action bar on respective windows and do not apply any theme on windows which will have action bar.

Read more here on **[Titanium Android Themes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes)**

Comment: very good explanation of the different methods. You might want to edit A1) method 1 to list the correct theme and say that it is in tiapp.xml

Comment: Thanks @miga :) .. .. Sorry that was typo error. :)